# Removing or skipping an image from an Image array if it fails to load?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a simple animation viewer for a sequence of map images using Javascript. I first load the images into a global array like this

```
while( datetime <= endDatetime) 
{
   var fname = getImgFnameFromDate(datetime);
   var imgAdd = new Image();
   imgAdd.src = fname;
   imgStore.push(imgAdd);   
   datetime.setMinutes(datetime.getMinutes() + 15);
}
```

and then loop through them with a short wait between each image.

```
function iter()
{         
   ++imgIndex;
   if (loopFlag) imgIndex = imgIndex % imgStore.length;
   document.getElementById("map").src=imgStore[imgIndex].src;
}
```

Now, the maps are made in near real time and occasionally some will be missing. The file fails to load giving instead a broken link image in the midst of the animation. I would like to simply skip an image that did not load, either by skipping over it or removing it from the array.

I have tried using the image width attribute as a proxy for 'isLoaded' i.e. something like

```
function iter()
{         
   ++imgIndex;
   if (loopFlag) imgIndex = imgIndex % imgStore.length;
   document.getElementById("map").src=imgStore[imgIndex].src;
   if (imgStore[imgIndex].width == 0) iter();
}
```

However this is unreliable and often leads to an infinite loop as it appears to trigger before the images have had a chance to load.

I have tried specifying an onError function for the images, but I can't work out what that function should do. I really want some kind of isLoaded attribute, rather than an event. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a flag on the image object when it loads and test that flag later:

```
var fname = getImgFnameFromDate(datetime);
var imgAdd = new Image();
imgAdd.onload = function() {
    this.myLoadFlag = true;
}
imgAdd.src = fname;
imgStore.push(imgAdd);
```

Then elsewhere, you can check to see if the image has been loaded yet:

```
if (imgStore[imgIndex].myLoadFlag) {
   // image has been loaded
}
```

When using an onload handler, just make sure that you set it before you set the `.src` property otherwise, there are some cases in some browsers where you will miss the onload event if the image is already in the browser cache.

---

An alternate approach (perhaps simpler to use) would be to have a second array that only contains loaded images and your main code only uses that:

```
// place we first put images, they go into imgStore only when actually loaded
var imgPending = [];

var fname = getImgFnameFromDate(datetime);
var imgAdd = new Image();
imgAdd.onload = function() {
    imgStore.push(imgAdd);    // now that it's loaded, add it to the images we're using
}
imgAdd.src = fname;
imgPending.push(imgAdd);
```

Then, your code that uses `imgStore` will only ever see images that are actually loaded.  One downside to this is that images go into `imgStore` in load order, not necessarily in the order that you request them so the order this way could be different than your old way.

Comment: Thanks for that. However there still appears to be a problem. After creating the image array with the onload() behavior as you suggest, I try looping over the images skipping those without the myLoadFlag=true. Unfortunately it skips all the images. It seems as though this check gets triggered before the image has had a chance to load (or something like that). I made sure I was setting the onload() before .src. By contrast, if I let it just display all the images but print out to screen the value of this flag, it all looks correct; missing images are undefined and good images are true.

Comment: <continuing> so it seems that when given a bit more of a chance the images do load, but using the suggested solution falsely decides the images have not loaded, before they have had a chance to do so. I'd really like to 'force' the images to load, rather than it happening whenever the browser feels like it, if that is possible?

Comment: @user1282133 - You can preload the images with javascript when the page first loads rather than trying to load them via JS later when you need them.  That gives them more time to load before you need them.  There's no way to make them load any faster.  They take time to load.  FYI, this code doesn't falsely decide the images haven't loaded.  It tells you when they haven't loaded YET.  You're just expecting them to be loaded before they are ready.  Unless you go with a preload scheme, your code needs to WAIT until they have time to load.

Comment: @user1282133 - If you want help with waiting until they are loaded, we can do that too, but you haven't shown enough of what you're doing for me to really know what exactly to advise.

Comment: Thanks for the help, you're exactly right. I'll try and make what I'm doing clearer. The loading needs to take place when the user triggers it (by pressing play) because the images are maps of a physical quantity created in near real time from a network of sensors, and the most current images need to be used. I could force the user to reload the whole page and preload the images then, but that doesn't seem like the most elegant solution. The user also should have an option to refresh the animation and obtain the most recent images, again without reloading the whole page.

Comment: @Bogdanovist - Probably what you want to do is start the loading of the images, put up some progress indicator ("Now loading...") and then, when the images are loaded, it calls you back and you build the maps with them.